# pass listbox items to another listbox in another user control

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox-control

C# Window Application Form

I have Form1 and with its user control called uc1, this uc1 will pop out a window form called Form2 when I select a value in the combobox.

In this Form2 I have a listbox1 with items, when I click 'Continue' button, it will pass all the items in my listbox1 to listbox2 in uc1.

How should I do the coding on the Form2 button_click?

How should I pass the value to listbox2?

Comment: if you can tell us which language you are using it would be much more simple for us to tell you what to do.

Comment: Sorry, I am doing on C# windows application form..thanks

Comment: What actually is the question for you? Do you mean how to organize that correctly in architecture meaning or your are not sure about technical part?